# Android - set layout label programmatically

Tags: android

How to programmatically set label in LinearLayout defined in XML?

Comment: Do you mean set new id?
Just use "setId()" in your .java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inflate desired layout in the layout you want.

Here is an example

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp, null);
        LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.glavenfrejm);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parametri = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        parametri.addRule(LinearLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        rl.addView(v, parametri);
```

And this question has been answered thousands time. Look around, more next time :)

Cheers.

Comment: Nope, this is not the solution. I need to change label programatically